# Default Recovery Partition behavior for Lenovo

Tags: lenovo-laptop, system-restore, partition-recovery, recovery-partition

I've got Lenovo G5045 laptop.

On default It has 2 visible partitions:

1. Windows 8 OS (`C:`)
2. Lenovo (`D:`)

and invisible recovery partition, efi, oem.

The `C:` drive is huge, it was about 800 GB. As my harddrive is 1 TB, I shrank the `C:` Drive. Now it is 120 GB in size and I've got 2 new partitions for my misc storage.

Now if I restore my laptop with the default recovery partition

1. Will it Work?
2. Will it delete my 2 partitions (with all of my contents) and set the `C:` drive to default size (back to 800 GB)?

Or will it restore everything on `C:` drive only and won't touch my partitions?

Comment: 4 primary partitions is the limit, you may have hosed your recovery partition by making too many partitions. Always back up your data before recovery. Most recovery software's will wipe all partitions and start over reformatting and partitioning the disk, then restore it to factory like condition. Did you make your recovery DVD's or flash drive?

Comment: I tried System image backup on DVDs and itgives me an error class not registered...

Comment: I would buy a usb flash drive 32gb or larger and use that to make recovery media.